# Find exact FK matches

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Have a very large table (over 200 million rows)
sID int, wordID int (PK sID, wordID)

Want to find the sID's that have the exact same wordID's (and no extras)
For a sID with over 100 wordID the chance of an exact match goes down so willing to limit it to 100
(but would like to go to 1000)

If this was school and sID were classes and wordID were students.
Then I want to find classes that have the exact same students.

sID, wordID
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 2
2, 3
3, 1
3, 4
5, 1
5, 2
6, 2
6, 3
7, 1
7, 2
8, 1
8, 1

sID 6 and 2 have the exact same wordID's
sID 5, 7, and 8 have the exact same wordID's

This is what I have so far
I would like to eliminate the two delete #temp3_sID1_sID2 and take care of that in the insert above
But I will try any ideas
It is not like you can easily create a table with 200 million rows to test with

```
  drop table #temp_sID_wordCount
  drop table #temp_count_wordID_sID 
  drop table #temp3_wordID_sID_forThatCount
  drop table #temp3_sID1_sID2
  drop table #temp3_sID1_sID2_keep
  create table #temp_sID_wordCount  (sID int primary key, ccount int not null)
  create table #temp_count_wordID_sID  (ccount int not null, wordID int not null, sID int not null, primary key (ccount, wordID, sID)) 
  create table #temp3_wordID_sID_forThatCount  (wordID int not null, sID int not null, primary key(wordID, sID))
  create table #temp3_sID1_sID2_keep  (sID1 int not null, sID2 int not null, primary key(sID1, sID2))
  create table #temp3_sID1_sID2  (sID1 int not null, sID2 int not null, primary key(sID1, sID2))
  insert into #temp_sID_wordCount 
  select sID, count(*) as ccount 
   FROM [FTSindexWordOnce] with (nolock)
   group by sID 
   order by sID;
  select count(*) from #temp_sID_wordCount where ccount <= 100;  -- 701,966
  truncate table #temp_count_wordID_sID
  insert into #temp_count_wordID_sID 
  select #temp_sID_wordCount.ccount, [FTSindexWordOnce].wordID, [FTSindexWordOnce].sID 
    from #temp_sID_wordCount
    join [FTSindexWordOnce] with (nolock) 
      on [FTSindexWordOnce].sID = #temp_sID_wordCount.sID
     and ccount >= 1 and ccount <= 10
   order by #temp_sID_wordCount.ccount, [FTSindexWordOnce].wordID, [FTSindexWordOnce].sID;
  select count(*) from #temp_sID_wordCount;  -- 34,860,090

    truncate table #temp3_sID1_sID2_keep
    declare cur cursor for 
    select top 10 ccount from #temp_count_wordID_sID group by ccount order by ccount

    open cur
    declare @count int, @sIDcur int
    fetch next from cur into @count
    while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    begin
      --print (@count)
      --select count(*), @count from #temp_sID_wordCount where #temp_sID_wordCount.ccount = @count
      truncate table #temp3_wordID_sID_forThatCount
      truncate table #temp3_sID1_sID2

      -- wordID and sID for that unique word count 
      -- they can only be exact if they have the same word count
      insert into #temp3_wordID_sID_forThatCount 
      select       #temp_count_wordID_sID.wordID
                 , #temp_count_wordID_sID.sID
      from #temp_count_wordID_sID
      where #temp_count_wordID_sID.ccount = @count
      order by  #temp_count_wordID_sID.wordID, #temp_count_wordID_sID.sID 

      -- select count(*) from  #temp3_wordID_sID_forThatCount

      -- this has some duplicates 
      -- sID1 is the group 
      insert into #temp3_sID1_sID2
      select w1.sID, w2.sID
        from #temp3_wordID_sID_forThatCount as w1 with (nolock)
        join #temp3_wordID_sID_forThatCount as w2 with (nolock)
          on w1.wordID = w2.wordID
         and w1.sID <= w2.sID         
       group by w1.sID, w2.sID
       having count(*) = @count
       order by w1.sID, w2.sID

      -- get rid of the goups of 1      
      delete #temp3_sID1_sID2  
      where  sID1 in (select sID1 from #temp3_sID1_sID2 group by sID1 having count(*) = 1)

      -- get rid of the double dips         
      delete #temp3_sID1_sID2
       where #temp3_sID1_sID2.sID1 in 
              (select distinct s1del.sID1 -- these are the double dips 
                from #temp3_sID1_sID2 as s1base with (nolock) 
                join #temp3_sID1_sID2 as s1del with (nolock)
                  on s1del.sID1 > s1base.sID1 
                 and s1Del.sID1 = s1base.sID2)

      insert into #temp3_sID1_sID2_keep      
      select #temp3_sID1_sID2.sID1
           , #temp3_sID1_sID2.sID2
        from #temp3_sID1_sID2 with (nolock)
        order by #temp3_sID1_sID2.sID1, #temp3_sID1_sID2.sID2

    fetch next from cur into  @count
    end
    close cur
    deallocate cur

 select *
 FROM #temp3_sID1_sID2_keep  with (nolock)
 order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I see, the task is to find equal subsets.

First we can find pairs of equal subsets:

```
;with tmp1 as (select sID, cnt = count(wordID) from [Table] group by sID)
select s1.sID, s2.sID
from tmp1 s1
    cross join tmp1 s2
    cross apply (
        select count(1)
        from [Table] d1
            join [Table] d2 on d2.wordID = d1.wordID
        where d1.sID = s1.sID and d2.sID = s2.sID
    ) c(cnt)
where s1.cnt = s2.cnt
    and s1.sID > s2.sID
    and s1.cnt = c.cnt
```

Output is:

```
sID        sID
----------- -----------
6           2
7           5
8           5
8           7
```

And then pairs can be combined into groups, if necessary:

```
sID         gNum
----------- -----------
2           1
6           1
5           2
7           2
8           2
```

See details in SqlFiddle sample below.

[<kbd>**SqlFiddle Sample**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4879a/5)

---

The other approach is to calculate hash function for every subset data:

```
;with a as (
    select distinct sID from [Table]
)
select sID,
    hashbytes('sha1', (
        select cast(wordID as varchar(10)) + '|'
        from [Table]
        where sID = a.sID
        order by wordID
        for xml path('')))
from a
```

Then subsets can be grouped based on hash value.

[<kbd>**SqlFiddle Sample**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20ddd/3)

The last one took less than a minute on my machine for a test data of about 10 million rows (20k sID values up to 1k wordID each). Also you can optimize it by excluding sIDs having no wordID count matches to any other.

Comment: It works on the sample data but on the large table it did not finish in 7 hours so I cannot verify.

Comment: Awesome approach but I am having a slight problem.  I need to go with max word count of 600 or I get string or binary data would be truncated error.  And if I take out the hashbytes I still get the error so it is in the for XML.  But at limit of 600 it ran in less two minutes.

Comment: @Blam, I recall I encountered this problem with some internal `for xml` limitation already, you may try split sIDs into batches of 50-200-500-1000k rows. Also `hashbytes` input has limitation of 8000 bytes. So, possibly you will have to split it's input into 8k parts, where it exceeds, then calc hash of every part and concat hashes.

Comment: Actually I may just do it in .NET.  That is data I am parsing in .NET and loading.